# Difference between backticks and no-backticks in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the difference difference between these two approaches?

```
SELECT name FROM `users`
SELECT name FROM users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the former has quoted the table name. This allows table names which collide with operators - for instance, you could have a table named "like". It also allows those whose names contain spaces or special characters.